# Proving that the 2 analytic functions are constant

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $$f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)\,\text{ and }\,g(z)=s(x,y)+it(x,y)$$be two analytic functions on a region D. Suppose$$\left|f(z)\right|^2+\left|g(z)\right|^2=r$$where $r$ is a fixed real number. Show that $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are constant functions.

I'm thinking of showing that $u$ and $s$ are constants, or $|f|$ and $|g|$ are constants, and either of which will lead to the desired result. I've tried making use of Cauchy-Riemann equations but I'm not getting anywhere. Any hints?

Comment: I'm really not sure how to apply the Cauchy-Riemann equations either. Here's what I got so far (this is not an answer):

Comment: To show that $f$ and $g$ are constant, we need to show that $f'=u_x+iv_y=0$ and $g'=s_x+it_y=0$. Namely, $u_x \equiv u_y \equiv 0$ and $s_x \equiv t_y \equiv 0$.

If $f$ and $g$ are analytic, then the Cauchy-Riemann equations dictate that $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$ for $f$ and $s_x=t_y$ and $s_y=-t_x$ for $g$.

Also, $|f(z)|^2+|g(z)|^2=r$ implies $$(u^2+v^2)+(s^2+t^2)=r.$$ Differentiating both sides with repsect to $x$ gives $$uu_x+vv_x+ss_x+tt_x=0$$
and with respect to $y$ gives
$$uu_y+vv_y+ss_y+tt_y=0.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the imposed condition, $|f(z)|^2+|g(z)|^2=r^2$, it follows that modulus of each analytic function is oscillating on  $D$ (i.e. $|f(z)|=r\cos(\theta), |g(z)|=r\sin(\theta)$). But by  maximum modulus principle the modulus of an holomorphic function cannot exhibit a true local maximum that is properly within $D$. Hence $f, g$ must be constant functions.

Comment: I get the main idea, but not completely. How does the oscillation guaranteed the existence of maximum within D? Can't seem to visualize it...

Comment: @Sapphire Draw the graphs of real functions $x(\theta)=r\cos(\theta}, \: y(theta)=r\sin(\theta)$ in the same system of axes. The graphs of the functions $z\mapsto |f(z)|$,

Comment: @Sapphire Sorry for the above incomplete comment.  The graphs of functions $z\mapsto |f(z)|, z\mapsto |g(z)|$ are 3D waving surfaces.

Comment: Ok, another part which I don't quite understand is why is the imposed condition sufficient to show the oscillation?

Comment: @Sapphire  The oscillatory property results from the equation $x^2+y^2=r^2$ that is verified by $|f(z)|$ and $|g(z)|$. Moreover, the functions $\cos$ and $\sin$ have distinct points of maxima.